# Proof mistakes (what is the mistake)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, logic, proof-writing

Good evening community,

Can anyone advise me on where I went wrong with this proof.

[image]

Comment: Why do you think line 12 is right? Without writing, I got that c is not small, perhaps it would help you to write out all known statements at any point

Comment: Here's essentially how it works. If Small(c), then there's two possibilities, Small(d) or Small(e). Small(d) cannot hold, because otherwise from 3 we have not Small(c), contradiction. Therefore, we have Small(e). Using the contrapositive of 4, we get not Cube(b). Then using 1 we get Small(b). So this is how Small(c) implies Small(b).

Comment: You should use premise 2

Comment: for which one of them?

Comment: @markjohn Once you have assumed Small(c) do an $\rightarrow$ Elim with premise 2.

Comment: I just submitted the one I did after I used → 
→
 Elim with premise 2. but it came out wrong. I do not know why. would you please show me how it is done

Comment: @markjohn Can you upload your newest attempt?

Comment: Can anyone explain to me why is my proof wrong ? thank you all

Comment: FYI : please do not repost questions as you [attempted to do](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2475721/272831).

Comment: ok, I could not find this one that's why I reposted it. but when I found it, I deleted the other one

Comment: How can I know if someone asked a question before me even if it is no answered ?